# angular-pdfjs-viewer - Message: stream must have data

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-directive

I am struggling to get `angular-pdfjs-viewer` working in my angular app that's written in `Typescript`.

I am always getting a red error message with the text:

> PDF.js v1.7.354 (build: 0f7548ba)
>
> Message: stream must have data

The PDF data is coming from an ASP.NET WebAPI controller, and the architecture of our application has the front facing website and the API both deployed as two independent web applications.

Due to this, I am wanting to download the PDF in the angular controller, and set the PDF source to the `data` attribute of the directive.

The WebAPI returns the PDF like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("invoice/{id}/originalpdf")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetInvoiceSourceImagePdf(string id)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetMyId();


    var bytes = await _serviceThatReturnsByteArray(id);

    return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}
```

I don't see an issue with the above.  In the browser, if I hit this endpoint, I get the document rendering exactly as expected.

On the front-end side:

- We're using the `angular-pdfjs-viewer` from https://github.com/legalthings/angular-pdfjs-viewer
- We're including (via `BundleConfig`), sources in the order of: `pdf.js`, then `angular.js` and then finally `angular-pdfjs-viewer.js` (with other application required dependencies in between)
- I am using the PDF.js dependency that "ships" with `angular-pdfjs-viewer.js`

The angular controller looks like this:

```
module MyApp {
    class PdfDialogController {

        public static $inject = ["$scope", "$window", "$log", "$uibModalInstance", "$http"];

        pdfData: Uint8Array;

        constructor(/*stuff*/){
            this.$http.get(the_url, { responseType: 'arrayBuffer' })
                .then((t) => {
                    this.pdfData = new Uint8Array(<ArrayBuffer>t.data);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And in the view, we have:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="pdf-container">
        <pdfjs-viewer data="vm.pdfData"></pdfjs-viewer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inspecting the network in the browser, the PDF content **is** downloaded.

`t.data` in the controller contains data that starts with

```
%PDF-1.3\n%����\n1 0 obj\n[/PDF /Text]
```

However, the views shows this:

[image]

And the console outputs an error message:

```
Error: An error occurred while loading the PDF.
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I determine what the issue is with the PDF data (if there is one).

Comment: hi have you tried to make your contreller (it's returning an ActionResult) something like return Ok(File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf));

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, since the controller action returns an `ActionResult`.  Also, I ended up figuring out what the issue was - see my answer.  Thanks for the comment though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that I was using

```
{ responseType: 'arrayBuffer' } // camel case
```

when I should be using

```
{ responseType: 'arraybuffer' } // all lowercase
```

Once changed, the code I posted in the question worked perfectly.